# how to extract all the audio from .mp4 or .mkv video url using node js

Tags: node.js, audio, ffmpeg

how to extract all the audio separately from video of .mp4 or .mkv here is the url for the reference : https://ctvod.run/ctv/warden/the.amazing.spider.man.2014.dual.mkv
I'm able to extract single audio only from video url. i need to extract all the audio using
ffmpeg or any other useful library in node js
with command terminal im able to get proper result here it is my command : `ffmpeg -i test.mkv -map 0:a:0 -c copy output1.mov -map 0:a:1 -c copy output2.mov`

Here is my working code for extracting audio from video ( for single audio now )

```
    app.post('/convert', (req, res) => {
  const { inputPath, outputPath } = req.body;

  if (!inputPath || !outputPath) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Invalid request. Both inputPath and outputPath are required.' });
  }

  ffmpeg(videoPath)
    .output(outputPath)
    .noVideo()
    .format('mp3')
    .outputOptions('-ab', '192k')
    .on('end', () => {
      console.log('Conversion complete');
      res.json({ message: 'Conversion complete' });
    })
    .on('error', (err) => {
      console.error('Error during conversion:', err);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Conversion failed' });
    })
    .run();
});
```

Comment: I think multiple inputs are not supported, and the library is no longer manteined. Maybe you have to switch to a more traditional way, childProcess